# Karma fails to proxy html with the Angular 2 quickstart config

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've played around with the Angular 2 QuickStart and testing. We really need to separate out the html and css to accommodate for our designers, so using templateUrl etc. is critical. But as soon as I replace template with templateUrl and point to a html file, the tests start failing.

Karma reports "WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy base/app/test.html (socket hang up)", and looking at the network trace, it hasn't translated the URL. All JS is translated to /base/app, but no matter how I mess with files patterns and proxies, it keeps going for /app/test.html instead of /base/app/test.html. In the component, the templateUrl is set to "app/test.html". I've tried all possible variations there too.

The only thing that makes the tests pass is setting include:true for html in karma.conf.js, and pointing to /base/app/test.html in the templateUrl.
I had the impression proxying with karma would make "something" in between translate all requested urls?

I've used files from release and latest commits on the quickstart repo.

**Edit:** This has now been fixed in the angular/quickstart project. :)
https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/329#issuecomment-271800205

Comment: Added an issue in the quickstart repo for good measure: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/329

Comment: Are you compiling your templates in the tests?

Comment: Yes, didn't modify the test sample from the quickstart repo. It does the right async and compileComponents stuff. https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/app/app.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem when testing the quickstart just right now. I was able to fix it just by changing the `appAssets` in the `karma.conf.js` from the original `base/app/` to `/base/app/`

From what I understand about the problem is that if you are trying to proxy `/app/`, which is what is used in the quickstart's `karma.conf`

```
var appAssets  = 'base/app/'

proxies: {
  "/app/": appAssets
},
```

why would you replace it with a path that *doesn't* also have the `/` in front. That would cause `/app/` to be `base/app/`, which it not the same, when you consider how URLs are resolved.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was sure I'd tried that combination too.
It might have been a rogue karma server when I fiddled with it yesterday. Got some weird behavior when comparing yesterdays project to a blank quickstart. The first one might have had the invalid config while I messed with the second. Or I didn't manage to restart karma each time. Who knows. This works. :) Thanks a lot.
I guess the zealous moderators here might want to tag this as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434792/karma-proxies-are-not-working.